# Lookup based on concatenation of values

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I'm trying to return a value from a DE based on a concatenated lookup, but am having some trouble.
 I know how to concatenate Attribute Values, but not sure how to get that to lookup against the DE to return a value. 
 Customerid and userid both have duplicates and need to be concatenated to be unique.

Sendable DE

| customerid | userid | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| art | 5643 | c@d.de |
| art | 6643 | r@d.fr |
| jup | 5643 | c@h.pt |
| kit | 5643 | c@d.se |

Offertable

| customerid | userid | offer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| art | 5643 | 100 |
| art | 6643 | 75 |
| jup | 5643 | 50 |
| kit | 5643 | 10 |

```ampscript
%%[

Var @customerid, @cid, @row, @rows, @userid, @uid,@cuid, @offer, @rowcount

Set @cid = AttributeValue("customerid")<br>
Set @uid = AttributeValue("userid")<br>
Set @cuid = Concat(@cid,@uid)

Set @rows = LookupRows("offertable", "offer", "customerid",@cid,"userid",@uid, @cuid)<br>
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
set @row = row(@rows,1) 
set @offer = field(@row,"offer")
else 
No rows found
endif
 ]%%

OFFER : %%=v(@offer)=%%
```

Comment: You should not concatenate the values, as this will search for the string in a single column. Instead, use LookupRows to lookup the values in both columns respectively, as described by Adam Spriggs here: https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a wrong syntax in `LookupRows` function. I would try this:

```
Set @rows = LookupRows("offertable", "customerid",@cid,"userid",@uid)
```

Full code:

```
%%[

Var @customerid, @cid, @row, @rows, @userid, @uid, @offer, @rowcount

Set @cid = AttributeValue("customerid")<br>
Set @uid = AttributeValue("userid")<br>

Set @rows = LookupRows("offertable", "customerid",@cid,"userid",@uid)<br>
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
set @row = row(@rows,1) 
set @offer = field(@row,"offer")
else 
No rows found
endif
]%%

OFFER : %%=v(@offer)=%%
```

And yes, you shouldn't concatenate the values.